# Передать данные из JSONObject из активити во фрагмент

Tags: json, kotlin, android-fragment, android-shared-preferences, android-bundle

Как передать JSONObject, созданный в активити и сохраненный в sharedPreferences в поля TextView фрагмента? Разумеется, каждое значение из JSONObject надо преобразовывать в String. Наверняка как-то через Bundle, но идеи пока нет. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: как насчет ViewModel, Static(java) или Object(kotlin)? мы просто можете создать "общий ресурс", а не передавать от одного к другому.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае вы можете в фрагменте переопределить метод onViewCreated и в нем взять ваш JSONObject из SharedPreferences. Взять данные из JSONObject можно следующим образом - jsonObject.get("NeededString") где NeededString имя поля.